# FontFactory.getFont not get font style

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem when dealing with font using in itext ( I used very old versioon 2.1.7 for some reason..)

This is how I registered and loaded font:

```
FontFactory.register(path +"/"+FONT, "IPAPMINCHO");
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("IPAPMINCHO",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED,9.5f, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
BaseFont baseBold = font.getBaseFont();
```

And how I using it for overlay the pdf

```
 stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(path + PdfCreator.DEST));         
 PdfContentByte canvasText = stamper.getOverContent(1);
 canvasText.beginText();
 canvasText.setFontAndSize(baseBold, 9.5f);   
 canvasText.moveText(72f, 788f);
 canvasText.showText(entity.getBookingDate());
```

The problem is that, text display on PDF file not in bold style I've set when register, it is display in normal style

What happened there?

Comment: You use iText 2.1.7 *for some reason*. Fix that reason! Don't treat the symptom, but solve the problem by using a more recent version of iText.

Comment: The most recent version of iText is `7.1.1`.

Comment: Can you ensure (Adobe Reader's File > Properties > Fonts) that the font loading/registering worked? Because if not, a default font (e.g. Helvetica) would be used...